Is it possible to use single keytab file on server for authenticating users from different realms accessing server by same name?
I have two AD forests, and I do not want them to trust each other. I also do not want them to trust any other "third" forest.
I want to make web service with Kerberos authentication to be transparently accessible by all users from those two forests.
I can create service accounts in both forests, set SPNs for them and create a keytab with two "credential lines".
Will this possibly work? Should I have any special logic to support authentication from both realms?

Yes, as long as the GSSAPI acceptor context created by the service doesn't require any particular principal name.
For example, Apache's mod_auth_gssapi defaults to not specifying an acceptor name and will accept tickets for any service key that's in your keytab, while (as a non-web example) OpenSSH's sshd does look for a specific "host/<fqdn>" name in the keytab unless configured otherwise.
In addition to per-application configs, the MIT Kerberos library has a global krb5.conf parameter ignore_acceptor_hostname to override such checks even if the service does specify a principal.
(I don't know what Java does.)
